# jQuery focus on content of input / textarea - not working properly in IE8

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I want the input fields on my site to select all the text when the user first clicks on them, but in IE8 the text is selected for a split second then reverts back to normal. Works fine in FF.

My js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //HTML DOM document is ready
    // Add this behavior to all text fields
    $("input[type='text'], textarea").live("focus", function(){
                                         // Select field contents
                                         this.select();
                                         });
});
```

Any ideas? I've tried adding ".focus()" after ".select()" and bizarrely enough it works, but throws loads of js errors in FF and IE.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.select()` on a jQuery object instead of the DOM element, and change the event to `click`. When you tab into the field, the text should be selected by default.

```
$("input[type='text']").live("click", function(){
       // Select field contents
      $(this).select();
  });
```

---

Well, this one was kicking me in the rear for some reason. I could swear I've done this before, but couldn't figure it out how.

This is the best I came up with. It postpones the `.select()` using `setTimeout()` until after the click event fires. Maybe there's a better way? Hope it helps.

```
$('input[type=text]').live('focus', function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){$th.select();}, 50);
});
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the field highlights each time I click - so if the user clicks into a field to edit it (say to correct an email address / spelling) they can't prevent the entire field from being selected each time.

Comment: @katebp - One solution might be to track which input has focus in a variable, and test in the `click()` handler if that same field was the last to have focus. If so, no `select()`. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: @katebp - Sorry for the delay. Updated my answer. Not sure if it is the best solution, but seems to work in IE8. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks.

Not sure why it works (I would have thought the element would be selected even if the "setTimeout(function(){$th.select();}, 50);" was replaced with "$th.select();" but it doesn't..?), but it works!

Comment: @katebp - Yeah, its a strange one. It appears as though the order of events is such that `click` takes place after `focus`, so the click immediately cancels the effect of the `.select()`. Delaying the `.select()` for 50 milliseconds ensures that it takes place *after* the click. Glad it works for you!