# Select entire contents of input and textarea on focus with Bootstrap/jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input

I have text in both input and textarea fields in a form in a Bootstrap modal. I want it so that when the user clicks in the text the whole field value is selected, as these are pre-populated urls and html fragments that they need to copy.

I have read that a timeout is needed, and have used the method at [jQuery focus on content of input / textarea - not working properly in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802803/jquery-focus-on-content-of-input-textarea-not-working-properly-in-ie8)

```
$('input[type=text]').live('focus', function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){$th.select();}, 50);
});
```

But each time I open the modal I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'`. I'm wondering if it is because I am only setting my input values as the modal is opened?

You can see it in action if you go to http://culturepics.org/ and click any 'Add this' button.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of jQuery you're using, but .live has been deprecated. Have you tried using your code with `.on`? http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Twitter Bootstrap working on your page then `.live()` will definitely not work. You're using a deprecated function of jQuerys. [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is what you need in this case.

From jQuery

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: Thanks to you and @pedalpete - that was exactly it (I'm on latest Bootstrap). Schoolboy error, and the danger of Googling old code! Cheers